# Check array for duplicates, return only items which appear more than once

Tags: c#, arrays, string, text, duplicates

I have an text document of emails such as

```
Google12@gmail.com,
MyUSERNAME@me.com,
ME@you.com,
ratonabat@co.co,
iamcool@asd.com,
ratonabat@co.co,
```

I need to check said document for duplicates and create a unique array from that (so if "ratonabat@co.co" appears 500 times in the new array he'll only appear once.)

Edit:
For an example:

```
username1@hotmail.com
username2@hotmail.com
username1@hotmail.com
username1@hotmail.com
username1@hotmail.com
username1@hotmail.com
```

This is my "data" (either in an array or text document, I can handle that)

I want to be able to see if there's a duplicate in that, and move the duplicate ONCE to another array. So the output would be

```
username1@hotmail.com
```

Comment: show us your attempt!

Comment: @Liam Dupe is for JavaScript but question is for C#...

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use Linq's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
var input = new string[] { ... };
var output = input.Distinct().ToArray();
```

You may also want to consider refactoring your code to use a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a simple array, as it will gracefully handle duplicates.

---

To get an array containing only those records which are duplicates, it's a little moe complex, but you can still do it with a little Linq:

```
var output = input.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                  .ToArray();
```

Explanation:

- `.GroupBy` group identical strings together
- `.Where` filter the groups by the following criteria

  - `.Skip(1).Any()` return true if there are 2 or more items in the group. This is equivalent to `.Count() > 1`, but it's slightly more efficient because it stops counting after it finds a second item.
- `.Select` return a set consisting only of a single string (rather than the group)
- `.ToArray` convert the result set to an array.

---

Here's another solution using a custom [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Duplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        var a = new HashSet<T>();
        var b = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach(var x in input)
        {
            if (!a.Add(x) && b.Add(x))
                yield return x;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call this method like this:

```
var output = input.Duplicates().ToArray();
```

I haven't benchmarked this, but it should be more efficient than the previous method.

Comment: I want to check if something exists in the first array more than once, then move that to another array.

Comment: @Andy So you want to return 2 arrays? Can you please provide examples of what the output should be?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in in [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, by default the comparisons are case sensitive, if you want to make it case insenstive use the overload that takes a comparer in and use a case insensitive string comparer.

```
List<string> emailAddresses = GetListOfEmailAddresses();
string[] uniqueEmailAddresses = emailAddresses.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:** Now I see after you made your clarification you only want to list the duplicates.

```
string[] duplicateAddresses = emailAddresses.GroupBy(address => address,
                                                    (key, rows) => new {Key = key, Count = rows.Count()}, 
                                                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                            .Where(row => row.Count > 1)
                                            .Select(row => row.Key)
                                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g No, I created an anonymous class in the `GroupBy` that contains the count. However after reading your answer I think your way is better.

Comment: Yeah I realized that a few seconds after I posted the comment. This good solution, too, and micro-optimization aside, it really comes down to which one OP finds easiest to read.

Answer (score 1):

To select emails which occur more then once..

```
var dupEmails=from emails in File.ReadAllText(path).Split(',').GroupBy(x=>x)
              where emails.Count()>1
              select emails.Key;
```

Comment: I want an array with the duplicates, not distinct.