# Browse through an array for a specific amount of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [a,a,b,b,b,c]
```

The result(a new array) should only show all the values which are exactly 2 times in this array, e.g.: a

Do you guys know how I could realize this? Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `a`?

Comment: Are the array contents supposed to be `string`?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this or do you just want someone to do it for you?

Comment: looks like home work. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check array for duplicates, return only items which appear more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852273/check-array-for-duplicates-return-only-items-which-appear-more-than-once)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
var arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','c'];

var numberOfOccurrences = {};

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    numberOfOccurrences[item] = (numberOfOccurrences[item] || 0) + 1;
});

var duplicates = Object.keys(numberOfOccurrences).filter(function (item) { return numberOfOccurrences[item] === 2 });

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect. Could you explain me what the "?" does? Never saw it before.

Comment: It is the ternary operator, actually, it is a short form of the if-else statement. It has the following form: "condition ? execute if the condition is true : execute if the condition is false".  You can read more it about here: http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm

Comment: I've just edited the code above, so it is much shorter now, since I used JavaScript functions for filtering and itterating through the array. If you have any questions about the new code, feel free to ask me and I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create object and add properties with `forEach` loop and then use `filter` on `Object.keys` to return array as result.

```js
var arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','c'];

var o = {}
arr.forEach(e => o[e] = (o[e] || 0) + 1);
var result = Object.keys(o).filter(e => o[e] == 2);

console.log(result)
```